# Ordered Commutative Integral Domain with no elements strictly between 0 and 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers

Suppose that $A$ is an ordered commutative integral domain such that there are no elements $\epsilon \in A$ such that $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Q1: Is it true that $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Q2: Suppose that, additionaly, $A$ satisfies the Archimedean Property, that is, given $a, b \in A$, with $a>0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such $na>b$ (with the obvious meaning of $na$). Is it true that $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: There seems to be an obvious counterexamples to Q1. But anyhow, we wonder what you have done on the subject so far. Please add to the question according to our guidelines on question quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the obvious homomorphism $f:\mathbb Z\to A$, which is 1-1 since $A$ is ordered. (If $\underbrace{1_A+1_A+\ldots+1_A}_n=0_A$ for some $n$, then $0_A<1_A<1_A+1_A<\ldots< 1_A+1_A+\ldots+1_A=0_A$ gives a contradiction.) So we may assume that $\mathbb Z\subseteq A$.

The answer to the Q2 is yes, i.e. we claim that $A=\mathbb Z$ with the above identification. Toward a contradiction assume that there exists an element $a\in A\smallsetminus\mathbb Z$. If $a>0$, by Archimedean property we can find $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n=n\cdot 1>a$; choose minimal such $n$, and note that by $a>0$ this $n$ is greater than $0$. So $n-1<a<n$. By adding $-(n-1)$ we get $0<a-(n-1)<1$, which is in a contradiction with the initial assumption. If $a<0$, then $-a>0$ and $-a\in A\smallsetminus\mathbb Z$, so we get the contradiction by the previous case.

The answer to Q1 is no. The easiest way to see this is to use the compactness theorem to find the non-standard model of $Th(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot,0,1,<)$ (it is similar to the construction of a non-Archimedean field). But also you can define the order on $\mathbb Z[X]$ by (thanks to egreg): $f<g$ iff $f\neq g$ and the leading coefficient of $g-f$ is positive. One should check that this make $\mathbb Z[X]$ into an ordered ring.

Comment: Isn't it easier to define $f<g$ if and only if $f\ne g$ and the leading coefficient of $g-f$ is positive?

Comment: @egreg Yes, you are right. Thanks!